# using 'lighter' weight of a font

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to use the "Helvetica Light" font, which comes bundled with Helvetica.  To do this I read that I had to specify "Helvetica Light" AND font-weight: lighter.  I've gotten this to work only by doing this (**in SASS**):

```
  p    
    font: "Helvetica Light", Arial, sans-serif
    font-size: 12px
    font-weight: lighter
```

and in other instances,

```
 h2.light    
    font: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
    font-size: 12px
    font-weight: lighter
```

(or with font-family instead of font)

which is really weird and the only combos that works so far (combining all properties into 'font' doesn't work, and calling the `font:` as `font-family:` sometimes doesn't work.

In another rule, I wasn't able to get it to work unless I ONLY had `font-weight: lighter` with no font specified (but it inherited Helvetica).

Now I copied the exact same font styles as the `p` and put it in an `h4` and it no longer works.  Wtf?  What am I doing wrong/why is this so buggy?

**EDIT: THIS IS NOT A SYNTAX PROBLEM.  To the answers below, note that I am using SASS. No semicolons and brackets needed.**  Also the file I am editing is 5k lines long (a hand me down) and grouped into somewhat organized sections.  So I'd like to keep the sections intact until I can refactor it, but then I can't group all the p's and h2.lights together since they are in different sections. 
Thanks!

Comment: You can use it like this `p,h2.light,h4{}`, no need to copy same thing over and over again...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what finally worked for me was to have font-family as Helvetica, and font-weight as lighter (but not the condensed format, which doesn't work).

Answer (score 8):

Try this.

```
p
  font: 'Helvetica Light', 'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif
  font-size: 12px
  font-weight: 100
```

Just for reference, *lighter* works relative to the inherited value. It's better to use absolute values.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-boldness

Comment: None of the lower font weights do anything for me.  I know lighter is relative, but nothing else works for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

#### Note: this answer was written before the OP specified SASS. It applies to CSS only.

A couple of things you should do to clean this up:

#### Semi-colons

All your CSS rules should end with a semi-colon, such as `font-weight:lighter;`

#### Grouping

As you have 2 identical CSS rules, the fastest and most concise way to do it is this:

```
p, 
h2.light,
other_rules {
  font: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
```

Then for the one rule where you want a different font,

```
p{ font: "Helvetica Light", Arial, sans-serif; }
```

Be sure to put your exceptions **below** the general rules (i.e. in the order I've shown you here) because CSS is implemented in order, and a rule further down the document will take priority.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the OP didn't make the fact that they're using SASS noticeable enough until *after* we answered. So, it isn't a Syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  p, h2.light
    font: "Helvetica Light", Arial, sans-serif
    font-size: 12px
    font-weight: lighter
```

Answer (score 0):

inheritance, establish a base metric typography, so device doesn't crack-up style intersections

body[role="put something here"] h1, p, etc

```
font-size: 62.5%
```

Helvetica light, mix with unix-mac-windows-webfont (webfont needs js, may pull you up over edge

font-family

```
Helvetica Light, Helveticaneue Light, Calibri Light,  Helveticaneue, Helvetica, Gill Sans, Myriad Pro, Arial, Lucida Grande, sans-serif
```

degrade per Meyer, or try just 2 hl, ss... also, check out your mixin
https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/389

Sass for Web Designers by Dan Cedarholm and Chris Coyier